# How to configure testlink to connect to jira per user?

Tags: jira, testlink

How to configure Testlink wherein username and password in "Issue Tracker Management" is empty and will populate based on testlink user accounts?

OR

How to configure testlink wherein username and password in "Issue Tracker Management" is empty and will prompt for username and password whenever you try to add a new bug?

Answer (score 0):

You should set a generic JIRA user with enough rights.

So, I haven't checked it but the user only should have read-only rights if you don't want to allow create new issues.

I have configured in my Testlink instance a JIRA admin account and it works properly. I don't allow to create new issues through testlink because I have removed the link from the template.

Regards, David.

Comment: Hi David,
Thanks for your output, tried to use my jira user in testlink, and I'm able to create and link issue, the problem though is that the reporter would be my user account (always) even if another user is creating the issue. I'd like to know if there is anyway you can make the user dynamic in testlink to jira when creating issues.
Regards, Jiro

Comment: This is the reason cause we don't allow the issue creation from Testlink. I've never found anything related to this. Regards, David.